# Routing issue. No routes found, but I know these exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Noob here.

Trying to figure out how to display a method in my controller into my index page. Here is what I have thus far.

Controller -

```
 class SammichesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sammiches = Sammich.all
end
  def create
    @sammich = Sammich.find_by_name(params[:sammich][:name])
  end
  def random
    @sammichy = Sammich.rand(params[:sammich][:name])
  end
end
```

Routes-

```
Sammiches::Application.routes.draw do
resources :sammiches do
  get "random"
end
root :to => 'sammiches#index'
```

Index-

```
<h1>All my Sammiches</h1>
<%= form_for Sammich.new do |f| %>
<%= f.label :sammich %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.submit 'Find Sammich', :id => 'sammich_submit' %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Random sandwich", sammich_random_path %>
```

routes-

```
sammich_random GET    /sammiches/:sammich_id/random(.:format) sammiches#random
     sammiches GET    /sammiches(.:format)                    sammiches#index
               POST   /sammiches(.:format)                    sammiches#create
   new_sammich GET    /sammiches/new(.:format)                sammiches#new
  edit_sammich GET    /sammiches/:id/edit(.:format)           sammiches#edit
       sammich GET    /sammiches/:id(.:format)                sammiches#show
               PUT    /sammiches/:id(.:format)                sammiches#update
               DELETE /sammiches/:id(.:format)                sammiches#destroy
          root        /                                       sammiches#index
```

Error-

```
localhost:3000 - Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"random", :controller=>"sammiches"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your route it has `:sammic_id` in there as well:

```
sammich_random GET    /sammiches/:sammich_id/random(.:format) sammiches#random
```

Which means you need to pass an id to your URL helper `sammich_random_path` which you haven't.

Update your routes to this:

```
resources :sammiches do
  collection do
    get "random"
  end
end
```

After adding that your route would be just `/sammiches/random`

Comment: Interesssssting. Thanks! I do have a new error now, though. undefined local variable or method `sammich_random_path

Comment: Run `rake routes` again, I think the helper would now be `random_sammiches_path`.

Comment: You're a smarter man than  am. I owe you one. Thanks a lot! I get a new error on the link. undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. But that is an entirely different issue and one I can hopefully dissect.

Comment: If you want to get a random object from the database you can do `Sammich.order("RANDOM()").first` in your `random` action. Right now you're not passing it any params so it won't work...

Comment: <3. Voted for this answer. Good night!